# Как узнать ориентацию экрана на Android-е

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как сделать чтобы программа заработала и вывела информацию о том в кокой ориентации у тебя находится экран смартфона , если уже создал функцию  MainActivity:

```
private String getScreenOrientation(){    
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        return "Портретная ориентация";
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        return "Альбомная ориентация";
    else
        return "";
}
```

> то есть функция у меня есть, а вот как её вызвать из нужного места, например, при щелчке кнопки и тем самым узнать ориентацию экрана, не пойму.

Я новенький на этом сайте(и в программировании), так что заранее извините:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обработать нажатие кнопки, нужно использовать слушатель `OnClickListener`. Сделать это можно несколькими способами, вот один из них. Добавьте этот код в `onCreate()`:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);  // Получаем кнопку из ресурсов

// Присваиваем обработчик нажатия
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // Выводим всплывающее окно
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getScreenOrientation(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```